# Java HttpServletRequest isUserInRole not working properly (per request security) servlet api 2.4

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, resteasy

I am building a web application served by tomcat (with servlet api 2.4 and can't switch to servlet api 3.0 at the moment).
I'm trying to secure a certain url-pattern dynamically using HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole.

I have multiple servlets which are secured using the web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MySecuredServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/my/secured/servlets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <!-- This servlet won't be secured because only some of the servlets this dispatcher calls will be secured -->
    <url-pattern>/my/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/my/secured/servlets/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I also have some other servlets which I can't write in the web.xml file because I don't know them at build time.

I'm dispatching requests to some dynamically set servlets and some of them require authorization.

```
class MyDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    ...
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,
      IOException {

        // I am dispatching requests to dynamically set customServlets which I don't know at build time
        MyCustomServlet customServlet = MyCustomServlets.get(req.getPathInfo());
        if (customServlet != null) {

          if (customServlet.requiresAuthorization()) {
            // isUserInRole is not reliable. It returns false when it should return true. Why?
            if (!req.isUserInRole(ADMIN_ROLE_NAME)) {
              resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
              return;
            }
          }

          customServlet.doGet(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Further clarification:

At url-pattern **/admin** I serve a page which is secured in the web.xml file.

From that page I make XMLHttpRequests to the dynamic servlets and I expect the **isUserInRole** method to return *true* since the user has authenticated when accessing **/admin** initially.

But isUserInRole returns *false* for all requests until I refresh the **/admin** page in the browser. Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a RestEasy implementation of JAX-RS so this answer may only be valid for RestEasy.

It appears that Tomcat won't set authentication cookies on requests if one doesn't call request.session.getId() on a request.

So what I had to do was to call session.getId() in a request before making my own requests.

Afterwards req.isUserInRole(MY_ROLE) returned correctly.